# MYSQL BETWEEN operator

Tags: mysql

Here is my table (EMP)

```
mysql> select * from EMP;
```

[image]

I want to Use BETWEEN Operator in the Check statement for SAL attribute.

```
alter table EMP add check(SAL between 50000 and 100000);
```

[image]

I have insert a SAL value that violates the BETWEEN constraint to check whether my query works correctly or not.

```
insert into EMP values('2134','ARUN','TESTER','NO','1998-08-22','M',20000,2500,03); //I gave SAL as 20000 which is invalid in my case.
```

Instead of showing error, it accepts the invalid value!

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: use >= and <= instead of between

Comment: MySQL 5.7 and earlier does not support check constraints, so you will have to use at trigger instead.  I can't find a reference for MySQL 8; if that version supports them, then my duplicate link is partially invalid.  In any case, it appears that your version does not support check constraints.

Comment: @PhilippSander `SAL BETWEEN 50000 and 100000` is identical to `SAL >= 50000 AND SAL <= 100000`.

Comment: According to the docs, MySQL 8 doesn't support check constraints either: `"The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”."` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: I guess I better _check_ my sources before I comment next time :P

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Put the text as text in the question, select it and use the `{}` button in the editor toolbar to format it as preformatted (or code).